# "Нарисовать во всю (на всю) стену". Правильный предлог

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, смысл

В чём смысловая разница в данных предложениях? Какой вариант правильный?

Нарисовать **во** всю стену.

Нарисовать **на** всю стену.

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае можно предположить, что нарисованное по размеру **вписано** в стену  (напр. башня *размером во всю стену*), однако не заполняет собой всю её площадь в силу отличия своих пропорций от пропорций стены.

Во втором случае речь может идти о **заполнении площади** стены всевозможными граффити или картиной, формат (отношение сторон) которой выбран в соответствии с пропорциями стены.

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
**нарисова́ть** *сов. перех.*
**1.** Рисуя, изобразить кого-либо или что-либо.

Фреска [во всю стену](https://vk.com/artorama?z=photo-52808807_325705888%2Fwall-52808807_238), нарисованная черным маркером. Шон Салливан.

На первом этаже [на всю стену](http://izhlife.ru/town/54366-samye-krasivye-podezdy-izhevska-polki-s-knigami-i-raspisannye-steny.html) нарисована картина.

Получается, что нарисовать кого-то или что-то можно во всю стену: по высоте (снизу доверху) или по ширине (от края до края). Допустим, Эйфелеву башню, или портрет Цоя с гитарой, или стилизованную панораму Нью-Йорка.
Можно нарисовать и на всю стену: заполнить рисунком абсолютно всё пространство стены.

Оба варианта правильны, каждый — для своего вида изображения.

Answer (score 0):

Частотность выражений в Нацкорпусе разная: ***во всю стену*** ― 290 примеров, ***на всю стену*** ― 8 примеров.

Очевидно, что ***во всю стену*** имеет универсальное значение (и масштаб, и заполненность пространства),  а ***на всю стену*** ― это обычно **предмет** величиной во всю стену, закрывающий всю стену.

В комнате у него на всю стену был натянут шелковый **ковер** с изображением дракона. [Варлам Шаламов. Начало (1962)]

Но огромные рекламные **плакаты** на всю стену! За ее спиной я заметил ... панорамное **окно** на всю стену. Юноша ...видел себя в огромном, на всю стену **зеркале.**